# Calling WSO2DSS data service from silverlight (cross-domain call)

Tags: silverlight, cross-domain, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I need make cross-domain call of data service (created in WSO2DSS) from silverlight.

I know there must be the specific crossdomain.xml file in root of web server.

But I don't know how I store this file in web server root of WSO2DSS.